# How to use determiners after the coordinating conjunction AND?

Tags: conjunctions, determiners

I need to say: "Chinatown and Little Italy are the most colourful and liveliest neighbourhoods in New York City". I wonder if I must add the determiner THE before "liveliest".

Comment: No: the single determiner "the" determines the whole coordination "colourful and liveliest neighbourhoods in NY".

Comment: Using two different forms of superlative there can be confusing, because "the most" might be read as applying to both adjectives. Including another "the" would make that clearer. Another option is to reverse the order of the adjectives: "...the liveliest and most colorful".